# Bike build recommendation

Tags: gears, compatibility, build, gravel

Im planning to build a gravel bike and I already have the following:

- Flared Drop bar
- Tiagra STI R7000
- 10S Deore M4100 Sprocket 11-42
- 700c Rims
- Marin Alps Series Frame

What other components should I buy so that it wouldnt have any problem if I put it in all to my frame?

Im stuck with what RD and Hub should I buy so that it will be compatible to what I already have.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting close votes.  It's ***not*** seeking product recommendations - it's asking for parts compatible with those listed in order to finish a bike build.

Comment: Looks like the Marin Alps is a hybrid bike frame. A drop bar puts your hands pretty far forward. Usually this means that when used with a hybrid frame the frame will be too long. Have you taken this into account when picking the frame size? Also: R7000 is Shimano’s current 105 groupset, not Tiagra (the current Tiagra is 4700). Which do you have?

Answer (score 2):

The Deore M4100 cassette is a 10-speed cassette. It goes to any Shimano splined freehub body but you need an additional 1.85mm spacer if the freehub body is intended for road 11-speed cassettes (MTB 11-speed does not require the spacer). You choose the type of hub based on the frame, for example:

- 130mm over locknut diameter quick release hub
- 135mm over locknut diameter quick release hub
- 142mm M12 thru-axle

Shimano makes many good hubs for all attachments, for both rim and disc brakes. Select the spoke hole count to match your rims. Since you already have the STI shifters, you no longer have the choice of selecting either rim or disc brakes, you must use what you already have. For the front, you have a choice between hub dynamo or no hub dynamo; as a user of a hub dynamo I can heavily recommend it.

Are your shifters R7000 (meaning they'd be 105) or Tiagra (meaning they'd probably be 4700)? R7000 shifters are 11 speeds so not compatible with a 10-speed cassette so you have to change either the cassette or the shifters; changing the cassette is cheaper. 4700 is compatible with a 10-speed cassette but requires a rear derailleur intended for the standard 11-speed cable pull ratio. So I suspect the rear derailleur should use the Shimano road 11-speed pull ratio.

Comment: STIs are compatible with both discs and rim brakes. Depends on the frame and fork. I imagine you COULD use R7000 shifters with 4700 by blocking off one gear with limit screws, but that’s just a waste of money.

Comment: Disc STI lever is different from the rim STI lever, being hydraulic as opposed to mechanical. It might be possible to use mechanical discs with rim STI levers but why would one do that since hydraulic brakes are superior?

Comment: Road mech discs (like TRP spyre for example) are designed to work perfectly with rim brake levers. There’s a decent price gap between mech and hydro, some people don’t want to deal with hydro, etc. I agree that hydros are great, but to say “you no longer have the choice” is incorrect.